# Take day of week from date

Tags: java, localdate

I have problem with my program, in which I have to insert a random date (dd/MM/yyyy) and if the day is Friday or Saturday, it should print out "It's time for party". I insert dates with Friday or Satuday, but it still print's out "You should study". Can somebody help out?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, formatter);
    System.out.println(date.getDayOfWeek().name());

    if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals("FRIDAY")) {
        System.out.println("Time for party, because it is: " + date.getDayOfWeek());
    }
    else if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals("SATURDAY"))
        System.out.println("Time for party, because it is: " + date.getDayOfWeek());
    else {
        System.out.println("You should study! It is: " + date.getDayOfWeek());
    }
```

Comment: 09/06/2018 doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace string value to enum type **DayOfWeek.FRIDAY** or **DayOfWeek.SATURDAY**. As you comparing string with enum.

```
if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)) {
                System.out.println("Time for party, because it is: " + date.getDayOfWeek());
            }
            else if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY))
                System.out.println("Time for party, because it is: " + date.getDayOfWeek());
            else {
                System.out.println("You should study! It is: " + date.getDayOfWeek());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It worked. Is there a way to print"FRIDAY" as "Friday"?

Comment: String day = date.getDayOfWeek().toString().toLowerCase().substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+""+date.getDayOfWeek().toString().toLowerCase().substring(1);

Comment: Yeah you can ask here.

Comment: I mean, can I ask you in skype?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot it.

Comment: @GauravSrivastav Your comment gives the poorly readable and complicated solution. Rather use `date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)` as user7 suggested in [a comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774526/take-day-of-week-from-date#comment88556329_50774567).

Comment: Cool, we could do that way too.

Answer (score 3):

`LocalDate.getDayOfWeek` returns an enum of type `DayOfWeek`. But you are comparing a String with the enum.

You must do

```
date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a `DayOfWeek` instance with a `String` instance so they will never be equal as they are different types.

one solution is to call `toString` prior to calling equals:

```
if (date.getDayOfWeek().toString().equals("FRIDAY")){...}
```

or better use:

```
if (date.getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.FRIDAY) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)) {...} and still worked. But is there any way to print FRIDAY as Friday?

Comment: why don't you just change the print statement to `System.out.println("Time for party, because it is: Friday");` as when control goes inside the `if` statement you know for sure it's _Friday_. seems like the simplest solution to me...

Comment: @zaro If you need `Friday` you can do `date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)`

Comment: I did it @Gaurav Srivastav's way, even though I am a beginner and I don't know many of the methods and what they actually do.

Comment: @zaro If you'd like to know more about the methods you could read the [documentation for `DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) including [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-) or other parts of [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)